# Is this a valid way to count instances of objects?

Tags: java, object

Is this a valid way to count instances of objects? Or should I not override finalize?

```
public class MyClass{
    private int instances;
   public MyClass(){
       instances++;
   }    
   @Override
   public void finalize(){
       instances--;
   }
   public static int getInstances(){
       return instances;
   }
}
```

The solution doesn't have to be Thread safe

Comment: No. Mark `instances`as `static volatile`. And secondly, **never** override the `finalize` method.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't, you know, actually try it and find out ... no.

Comment: No; that's not thread-safe.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if I can't override finalize, what should i do?

Comment: @user2097804 just count how many instances of your classes you have. You can't really know when the GC will get rid of the unused instances of this class.

Comment: @user2097804 if you have to override the finalize method, remember to also call `super.finalize()` so Java's standard finalize actions also happen.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `finalize` will be run.

Comment: @HotLicks the only guarantee is that the finalize method will be called at some point before actual garbage collection of the object. We cannot know whether the object would still be in scope or reachable at this stage.

Comment: I meant to make instances static

Comment: [Here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/finalize-method-in-java-tutorial.html) is an interesting link about the finalize method...

Comment: Why does it not have to be thread safe? Are you assuming finalize necessarily runs in the thread that is creating the objects?

Comment: @RudolphEst - There is no guarantee that `finalize` will be run.  It's run on a "best effort" basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark `instances`as `static volatile`. And secondly, **never** override the `finalize` method. Also, in the code AS-IS, note that you can't access to `instances` variable in your `public static int getInstances` method.

Comment: What he's trying to do in `finalize` is decrement his own reference count. While that wouldn't really work anyway, it makes the rest kinda moot.

Comment: So where does instances get decremented?

Comment: @Ayman you won't know for sure, since this is the job of GC and you can't have control of this.

Comment: I thought so too.. SO the only way is when you manually destroy the / close the object, not when it automatically go out of scope and get GC.

Comment: @Ayman if you could implement the `Closeable` interface and make sure to always call the `close` method, then you could decrease the counter there.

Comment: Marking `instances` as `volatile` is unnecessary: Doing so won't make this method of tracking instances thread safe anyways.

Comment: Seriously @LuiggiMendoza - this answer is kinda wrong. WIthout a way to decrement the reference count it doesn't do what the OP is asking. I'm not going to bother (mainly because it's a holiday here and I'm about to go do something relaxing :) ) but off the top of my head the only way to even think about doing this is using weak references.

Comment: @BrianRoach I know is kinda wrong because you can't decrement the number of instances because you don't have control over it, but the only idea I came up with was implementing `Closeable` (but IMO even this won't be the right approach).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I had a similar real-world problem when exposing a streaming (network, pooled connections) operation to the end-user via an Iterable, trying to auto-close the stream if they didn't iterate through the whole stream or explicitly call a close/cancel method (without using a timeout). It sucks :) Basically you have to have a thread/timer that maintains a weak reference and can check the real reference count. The same could be applied here in some fashion.

Comment: @BrianRoach doing this lot of work for a real world case is very interesting, but for solving a simple curiosity (as it look in this case) I would say is not worth it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Agreed. Which is why I'm drinking a beer and about to go work on my dirtbike :)

Answer (score -2):

If I get what you are trying to accomplish, you want to keep count of the number of instances of MyClass that have been created in your application. If that's the case, you need to declare the instances variable and the getInstances method static.

```
public class MyClass{
   private static int instances;
   public MyClass(){
       instances++;
   }    
   @Override
   public void finalize(){
       instances--;
   }
   public static int getInstances(){
       return instances;
   }
}
```

Also, I would rename instances to instancesCount (or simply count) and do the same rename for the getInstances method.

Comment: The instance count increment in the constructor is not thread safe.  Two instances created concurrently in separate threads will result in the count being wrong.

Comment: *Overriding finalize is the way to go* ... no, it's not. There is absolutely no guarantee as to when it gets executed. It may never get executed during the life of the program (instead, only on exit).

Comment: @Keith, thread safety was not a requirement, but I agree with your comment. Use a volatile counter or synchronize over a lock.

Comment: I think the OP may have added "The solution doesn't have to be Thread safe".  I didn't see that originally anyway.

Comment: @Keith Unfortunately he's wrong given that he's trying to modify a static field via `finalize()`; that's not going to be called in the same thread, and post-increment/decrement is not an atomic operation. This answer is incorrect and sadly the OP has accepted it without understanding the myriad of problems with what he's attempting to do.

Comment: @RudolphEst The non-thread-safety was an incorrect non-requirement, as finalization takes place on a separate thread.